# Issues with pushing to Git

Tags: git, github

I'm pretty new to git and have been using it to push to for a class I'm taking. My professor has created a remote repository and I'm forking from that.

I've used the following process to clone the basic project and push back up my changes. However when pushing I always get an error:

First I clone the project using:

```
 git clone [An SSH Address]
```

Then I make changes to my files and add them using:

```
 git add [filepath & filename]
```

I then do a commit with:

```
 git commit -m "some message here"
```

Lastly, I attempt to push my changes to the repository with:

```
 git push
```

but get the following error:
     Access denied.
     fatal: could not read from the remote repository

```
 Please make sure that you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Like I said, I'm pretty new to git and version control in general, so maybe I'm just doing something silly. Any advice?

EDIT:

By running:

```
 git remote -v
```

I get:

```
 origin git@git.cis.***.edu:***/***.git <fetch>
 origin git@git.cis.***.edu:***/***.git <push>
 Sensitive info is blocked out with ***.
```

As far as I know I should be pushing to the originally cloned repo and it should be my own branch.

**SOLVED:**

Found out what was causing this issue. Before pushing back up my branch of the project, I was copying over the folder it was stored in. This caused

```
 git remote -v
```

to return

```
 origin git@git.cis.***.edu:***/***.git <fetch>
 origin git@git.cis.***.edu:***/***.git <push>
 Sensitive info is blocked out with ***.
```

instead of

```
 origin git@git.cis.***.edu:myusername***/***.git <fetch>
 origin git@git.cis.***.edu:myusername***/***.git <push>
 Sensitive info is blocked out with ***.
```

Comment: 1. did you setup ssh information correctly ?
2. make sure you have push rights for the repository 3. are the remote settings of the repository correct ? you can refer this interactive tutorial to learn the basics of git in few minutes of your time :) http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1 and headback to github for detailed* guidelines http://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial

Comment: So, there are a couple of things that could be the issue here. First of all, are you pushing to your professor's remote repo, or do you have your own remote fork? This would be different from the local clone that you have on your laptop, for example. Is the repo hosted on your school's network, or is it on GitHub or some other hosting provider? In your push command, you may need to specify the remote repo that you want to push to. What is the output of `git remote -v`? That's just a repo URI, it shouldn't contain any sensitive passwords or anything.

Comment: If there does happen to be any sensitive information, you can censor out whatever you need to, but be sure to leave enough info behind so that we can help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: I've check my ssh key on git against what I get by using ssh-add -l.

How would I check for points 2 and 3?

Comment: Thanks for the help.

git remote -v produces:


origin git@git.***.edu:***/***.git <fetch>
origin git@git.***.edu:***/***.git <push>

I've hidden sensitive info with *.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like your school is hosting the remote repos on the school's own network. Do you see your name in that URI, or do you see your professor's? Do you know if you're supposed to push to the original repo that you cloned from? If you are, is it supposed to be to your own branch? Also, it's preferable to add more information to questions by editing them into the original question, instead of leaving comments, if possible.

Comment: you can ask from professor about the access rights on if you're supposed to use your own or any other user login. for point 3. cd into your local repository on terminal and type `git config --get remote.origin.url`

Comment: @user2276280 you can answer your own question and then accept it after 48 hours, just fyi.